# Vim syntax file. match 'foo' and 'bar' independently in 'foobar'

Tags: regex, vim

In a vim syntax file I want to

- name one match `foo` followed by `bar`
- and another `bar` that follows `foo`

And have them both work.

Here is what I have so far

```
 syn match myFoo /foo\zebar/ display

 syn match myBar /foo\zsbar/ display
```

When I do that it only matches the latter one.
I cant get both `foo` and `bar` to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
syn match myFoo /foo/ contained
syn match myBar /bar/ contained
syn match myFooBar /foobar/ contains=myFoo,myBar
```

I've confirmed that it works. I have Vim coloring foobar where the foo is one color and bar is a different color. And this only happens if they are together as foobar; otherwise they are not colorized. I assigned them to different categories like this:

```
hi def link myFoo Keyword
hi def link myBar Type
```

You probably have this covered already.